# Bootstrap 4 menu positioning with image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm using this template:

http://bootstrap4.guide/

And I want to modify menu a bit, instead of having blue *Bootstrap 4* text, I'd like to have a image there. It's looking all fine until I look at mobile view.

I'm expecting to have my image in the same place as the text:
[image]

However my image happens to appear under hamburger menu:
[image]

This is what I have at the moment:

```
<nav id='topNav' className='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
  <div className='container'>
    <button className='navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-right' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapsingNavbar'>
      &#9776;
    </button>
    <a className='navbar-brand page-scroll' href='#first'><img src='logo.png'/></a>
    <div className='collapse navbar-toggleable-sm' id='collapsingNavbar'>
      <ul className='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <a className='nav-link page-scroll' href='#one'>Cards</a>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <a className='nav-link page-scroll' href='#two'>Flexbox</a>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <a className='nav-link page-scroll' href='#three'>5 Tiers</a>
        </li>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <a className='nav-link page-scroll' href='#four'>More</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul className='nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right'>
        <li className='nav-item'>
          <a className='nav-link page-scroll' data-toggle='modal' title='A free Bootstrap theme' href='#aboutModal'>About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've just replaced *Bootstrap 4* with this img tag: `<img src='logo.png'/>`. I'm quite new to bootstrap, if someone would help me to figure out how to sort this out, that'd be great.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle or plnkr? It's hard to help when we can't see you CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust the `navbar-brand` class as needed for your logo image..

```
/* responsive nav */
@media(max-width:48em) {
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.nav-item {
        float: none;
        margin-left: .1rem;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav {
        float:none !important;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        float:none;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-brand img {
        display:inline;
    }
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/7HJgyK6nxQ

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to divide the the hamburger and the logo in two equal parts by using bootstrap classes for small devices.(col-xs-6)

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <button className='navbar-toggler hidden-md-up' type='button' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#collapsingNavbar'>
          &#9776;
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <a className='navbar-brand page-scroll' href='#first'><img src='logo.png'/></a>
    </div>
</div>
```